# QML SplitView does not resize its content when the window shrinks

Tags: qt, qml, splitview

I have a QML vertical **SplitView**, split into 2 elements:

- The top element is a green rectangle
- The bottom element is a red rectangle

Both have a minimum height of 200.
Inside the bottom element there is a blue rectangle anchored to the bottom with a fixed height of 50.

It looks like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIpse.png) :

The issue is this: when I manually resize (shrink) the window from the bottom, the bottom item does not scale properly so the blue rectangle disappears under the window.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Move the handle a few hundred pixels to the top
- Resize the window from the bottom side to the top until the bottom item start becoming smaller

I get this result [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WLFT.png), and as soon as I move the handle, everything goes back to a normal state and the bottom item is resized as it should be [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apYFr.png).

Here is the QML code :

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    title: testSplitView
    visible: true
    x: 100; y: 100
    width: 1300; minimumWidth: 900;// maximumWidth: 1300
    height: 900; minimumHeight: 550;// maximumHeight: 900

    Rectangle{
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "darkGrey"

        SplitView{
            id: verticalSplitView
            anchors.fill: parent
            orientation: Qt.Vertical

            Rectangle{
                id: topRectangle
                SplitView.fillHeight: true
                SplitView.minimumHeight: 200
                color: "red"
            }

            Rectangle{
                id: bottomRectangle
                SplitView.minimumHeight:200
                color: "green"
                Rectangle{
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    height: 50
                    width: parent.width
                    color: "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work fine for me. The blue rectangle never gets covered up when I resize the window. I'm on Ubuntu using Qt 5.15.5.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Are you sure you did the same steps as me? It looks like this on my screen : https://streamable.com/nxwalm . I'm also on Ubuntu 18.04 using Qt 5.15 (I also tried with Qt 5.12 using QT.Controls 1)(it behaves the same on mint 20)

Comment: I see now. It only happens if you move the splitter handle first. I missed that step.